Calculating a weighted average of existing measures in Power Pivot
I have successfully created two measures (Measure1 and Measure2) and I want to get the weighted average of Measure2- Duration.
Here's how my data looks like and the weighted average I wish to get:

I've tried some variations of Calculate and Summarize but none have worked.
Eventually I wish to display this number in Power Pivot Chart.

maybe you can try this
Measure=AVERAGEX(values(rowcolumn), Measure2)

the row column is the column name for Cat1, Cat2, Cat3

But how do the weights of Measure1 come into play here?

could you pls provide some sample data and explain the calculation logic of weighted average?
